# Access: How can I create a button on a form to run a query and return result to the form

Tags: ms-access

I have created a query that filters a table correctly I then make this query my form data source. and it works perfectly. I use the macro builder to create a "go to next record" button and this also works perfectly and lets me step through the filtered forms

What I actually want to do is to attach the query to the button, not the form, so that the next button steps through the filtered table, but if I use other navigation methods in the form they see the entire table.

I created a button and selected run query, selected my query and all it did was open the table and apply the filter. It did nothing to the form.

What do I need to do to create a next record button on my form that lets me move sequentially through the list of filtered records using my form?

Comment: try to add code

Comment: Updated grammar/spelling

Comment: Please use correct tags - the people who watch the [access] tag looking for access control issues are often not the correct people to answer MS Access questions.  Those people would be watching the [ms-access] tag.

Comment: can you please add more detail to your question? maybe an image of your form or what kind of data you're looking at? is there a reason you don't want to use a sub form and have all of the relevant records the user is searching for appear in a sub form datasheet?